# iMessage shows the wrong name for a phone number

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

My iPhone 4 with iOS 6 is playing up in iMessage.  For one person, it is showing their Facebook name (a pseudonym) instead of the name I entered in the contact list (their actual name.)

Additionally, when I type their name, it displays their home phone number as an option which is not stored anywhere in my phone anymore.

For example, say I type **John** into the **To:** field.  It offers:

> **That Guy John**
>   mobile +61 4xx xxx xxx
>
> **John Smith**
>   home 03 xxx xxxx

They're the same person on the same linked contact card.  I want it to use the name **John Smith**, but if I choose **mobile**, it uses **That Guy John**.  Additionally, I've previously deleted the **home** number from my phone, and it's not stored on Facebook, so I don't know how it's getting it.

Is there a caching issue?  How can I make iMessage display the correct contact names and phone numbers?

Comment: Do you sync your Facebook contacts into the Contacts app?

Comment: I do, and I've gone through and linked and normalised my Facebook and Hotmail contacts so there's one unified entry for each person, with their proper name.

Comment: I found another contact with mismatched names and it too uses the Facebook name over the Unified name.  Maybe it's just a quirk of iMessage?  All the same, I'm a bit concerned about it caching deleted phone numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Try closing iMessage (Settings > Messaging > iMessage).
Turn off your phone and wait 5-10 minutes.
Tap Settings > Phone > My number and verify that your phone number is correct.
Finally, reopen iMessage (Settings > Messages), then go to Settings > Messaging > Send & Receive and see if the correct number is displayed under "Start a new session from".
Hope this helps you.